# cannot spot the Type Error reported by the Python Shell

Tags: python

Hi I'm realtively new to computer science and learning to code Python. Here is a section of the code that I have trouble with:

```
from uagame import Window
from time import sleep
window = Window('hello',300,200)
user = window.input_string('Enter string>',0,0)

x = window.get_width() - window.get_string_width(user)
y = window.get_height() - window.get_font_height(user)
window.draw_string(user_input,x,y)
sleep(2)
window.close()
```

It always display a Type error and I do not know the reasons. I've run similar codes with no problem
Here is the error:
    builtins.TypeError: get_font_height() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I imagine that `.get_font_height()` is attached to an object, and therefore the first argument is `self`. I suspect that if you don't try to feed it `user` it will work. I have not used `uagame` before though, so I'm not sure. Have you tried doing just `y = window.get_height() - window.get_font_height()`?

Answer (score 0):

What that means, I'm guessing, is that `window.get_font_height()` is a method that doesn't take an argument. Since it's `window.<method name>`, the first argument to `get_font_height` is probably going to be `self`! So you are passing a user to that function, which is, I'm guessing, the second argument.

Look up the documentation for uagame window.get_font_height and make sure you're using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The guesses of the other respondents are correct: `get_font_height` takes only the `Window` object as an argument, and receives that through the normal call sequence (i.e. the window is the `self` argument).  The font height is returned as an `int`.

There is no dependence whatsoever on your input string; that argument is not allowed, and that's why you got that error message.  Simply remove that and call as `window.get_font_height()`.